# How to unit test this class with almost 100% of coverage?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit5, powermockito

How to unit test this class with almost 100% of coverage?
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.stream.Stream;

```
public class StreamCommons<T> {
    public long contar(Stream<T> item) throws IOException {
        try (Stream<T> conteudo = item) {
            return conteudo.count();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Test the good cases with a real stream, test the bad case with mockito. That should do it. What is the problem you're having with that?

Comment: Please share your attempt and how much it covers the code?

Comment: Any test that calls this method with a non-null `Stream` will result in 100% test coverage. Test coverage only calculates the lines were called, not that there are assertions or that there is desired behavior.

Comment: What kind of coverage are you aiming at?  Statement coverage or branch coverage?  Due to the possible occurrence of exceptions, this might make a difference - depending on how clever your coverage tool is...